# Choose the single correct answer

Tags: mathematics, probability

If you choose an answer to this question at random, what is the chance that you will be correct?
A. 25%
B. 0%
C. 50%
D. 25%

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/multiple-choice-puzzle) and [other similar ones](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/if-you-choose-an-answer-to-this-question-at-random-what-is-the-chance-you-will), just with one option different...